# list.sort, but groupby ending numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have a list of items I would like to group by the last two ending numbers, so:

```
127658
012345
123456
123457
123458
012345
```

would sort as:

```
012345
012345
123456
123457
123458
127658
```

How is this accomplished by overloading list.sort?  The output would be very similar to say, an excel autofilter, "ENDS WITH 00"

Comment: your example is not too clear, since they would be ordered either by 2-ending-digit or by whole number.

Comment: let us know if any of the proposed answer responds to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No overload is needed. Just use a lambda:

```
list.OrderBy(Function(n) Cint(n.toString().Substring(n.toString().Length-2))).
     ThenBy(Function(n) n)
```

This is a really polished solution.

---

As **Steven Doggart** pointed out, you can check for numbers shorter than 2 digits:

```
list.OrderBy(Function(n) Cint(n.toString().
             Substring(n.toString().Length - Math.Min(n.ToString().Length, 2)))).
     ThenBy(Function(n) n)
```

---

Or, even simple, using part of **MarcinJuraszek**'s answer:

```
list.OrderBy(Function(n) n Mod 100).ThenBy(Function(n) n)
```

Comment: I like it!  However, you don't need the `, 2` at the end of the call to `SubString`.  Also, it would be nice to check the length to make sure it doesn't fail if the string is less than two characters in length.

Comment: @StevenDoggart Modified! Thanks!

Comment: Also added another possibility based on @MarcinJuraszek 's answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks quite easy. Compare function:

```
Public Shared Function CompareByLastTwo(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
    Return (x Mod 100).CompareTo(y Mod 100)
End Function
```

And usage:

```
Dim items as List(Of Integer)

(...)

items.Sort(CompareByLastTwo)
```

I assumed your items are `Integer`

Answer (score 0):

This should work (presuming a `List(Of String)`):

```
list = list.Select(Function(num) New With {
               .Num = num,
               .LastTwo = If(num.Length < 2, num, num.Substring(num.Length - 2))
           }).
        OrderBy(Function(x) x.LastTwo).
        ThenBy(Function(x) x.Num).
        Select(Function(x) x.Num).ToList()
```

If it's a `List(Of Int32)` the same approach:

```
intList = intList.
    Select(Function(num) New With {.Num = num, .Str = num.ToString()}).
    Select(Function(x) New With {
        x.Num,
        x.Str,
        .LastTwo = If(x.Str.Length < 2, x.Str, x.Str.Substring(x.Str.Length - 2))
    }).
    OrderBy(Function(x) x.LastTwo).
    ThenBy(Function(x) x.Num).
    Select(Function(x) x.Num).ToList()
```